# What is the correct HTTP status code to respond to a Create operation on a Resource with a OneToMany

Tags: http, rest, httpresponse

I have something of a simple usecase: User has a set of Privileges; when I create the User resource I do not want to also create Privileges; so, if a new User with new Privileges comes from the client, I want to respond with something along the lines of:

> I cannot create the User Resource because the Privileges it contains
>   do not exist.

At this point, the client can do a Create on the Privilege first and then add them to the User and create that.

The question is **what Error status code to use** for the HTTP response:

- 412 - Precondition Failed
- 424 - Failed Dependency

I also considered (but do not seem to fit the usecase):

- 400 - Bad Request
- 422 - Unprocessable Entity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

422 and 424 have a specific WebDAV meaning. So they don't apply.

412 is about a precodition the *client* requested. So it doesn't apply, too.

Maybe 409 Conflict could be used.

**Edit:** 409 Conflict is about the client asking the server to put the server's resources into an impossible or inconsistent state. So I think it applies to your sitation. As long as the referenced Privileges don't exist on the client, a User referencing them can't be created.

**Edit:** Take a look at http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the WebDAV nature of the 422 and 424. With these two out, I am still not sure what to use, just because 409 Conflict doesn't seem to apply here. Regarding the precondition in the CLIENT request, this is in fact the case, because the Client is the one that requested the creation of both User and Privileges, which is not permitted.

Comment: 412 is about preconditions the client spcified in request *headers* like `If-Unmodified-Since` or `If-None-Match`. They are not about resource relations.

Comment: @Eugen: 409 Conflict seems to be the right fit for your case. You could include the URI to create privileges in the response entity of the conflict response.

Comment: Just because something is defined in the WebDAV specs doesn't make it unsuitably here.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on codes from a HTTP extension like WebDAV to be propagated through the whole call stack. Better to play save and stick with plain HTTP/1.1.

Answer (score 1):

409 sounds good; the client can do a separate request to resolve the conflict, in which case the operation would have succeeded. (You could use a Link with a custom link relation to identify the resource the operation was in conflict with)

Comment: Thanks for agreeing with me. Now what about those WebDAV status codes? ;)